# is there a universal definition for "static class"?

Tags: oop, class, object, static

I thought I knew everything that was to know about static classes until I switch to java and learned that just about everything that cannot be done with a static class in C#, can be done in Java.

So if I were to say "a static class is a class that cannot be instantiated and that cannot have instance members and that is sealed and that cannot derive from any class other than Object", I would be guilty of assuming that what is true in one programming language is true in all programming languages.

Is there a universal definition to "static class" or is it just whatever the people who implemented the language wanted it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard for many OO concepts or how languages implement those concepts

Java doesn't have static classes, just nested static ones.  They are different things.

Comment: I think of a nested class as a class. I also think of a non-nested class as a class. But I understand what you are saying.